# Cache buster in angular 2

Tags: angular, browser-cache

I'm working on an angular 2 project and i want my browser to request for new files from server after every deployment. How can i achieve this?

Notes:

I enable cache in my .htaccess file on apache.

I am currently using angular cli 1.0.0-beta.22-1.

Edit:
Each time i run "ng build --prod" from angular cli, i want it to somehow add a cache buster like filename.js?ver=1.0.2 for all edited files

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">

Comment: Try adding ^^this to your index page

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy Thanks for your comment, but i think this turns off browser cache completely, which isn't what i want. I want to enable cache, but each time i run "ng build --prod" from angular cli, i want it to somehow add a cache buster like filename.js?ver=1.0.2 .

Comment: this exists now in 1.6.0 as per comments here :

allow output hashing to be configured #3885

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3885
 
This allows the output filename hashes to be configured during a build via a new build command option --output-hashing. There are four possible values:

none: no hashing performed
media: only add hashes to files processed via [url|file]-loaders
bundles: only add hashes to the output bundles
all: add hashes to both media and bundles

none is the default for the development target.
all is the default for the production target.

Answer (score 2):

this exists now in `@angular/cli 1.6.0` as per comments here :

allow output hashing to be configured #3885

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/3885

This allows the output filename hashes to be configured during a build via a new build command option

```
--output-hashing.
```

There are four possible values:

```
none: no hashing performed
media: only add hashes to files processed via [url|file]-loaders
bundles: only add hashes to the output bundles
all: add hashes to both media and bundles
```

none is the default for the development target.
all is the default for the production target.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular CLI version 1.0.0-rc.0 there is a build command:

```
--output-hashing=none|all|media|bundles (String) Define the output filename cache-busting hashing mode.
```